# Like operator with comma separated values using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have not able to getting my data using like operation

below is my code

```
Declare @Search varchar(100)
set @Search='Gender,Name,Age'
select * from Table_SampleData where FieldName LIKE '%' +  @Search + '%'
```

I have my table data is like below

Table_SampleData

```
FieldName   Values
Gender       Male
Name         Mazhar
Age          31
Location     Hyderabad
```

My output should be

```
FieldName   Values
Gender       Male
Name         Mazhar
Age          31
```

Comment: Do you really need to use this `EAV` model ?

Comment: Hellow this is not duplicate question, i use this query also WHERE (',' + RTRIM(MyColumn) + ',') LIKE '%,' + @search + ',%' but not working.

Comment: Dear that answr is not helping then how its duplicate. @Mureinik

Comment: Should be `where ',' + @Search + ',' LIKE '%,' + FieldName + ',%'` . Now do you see how complicates your solution be if you use this model ?

Comment: Can you answer i will update your answer please. @Squirrel

Comment: Dear your answer is giving me correct output thank you, please update your answer i will mark as answer. @Squirrel

Comment: No worries. This thread is already closed. Can't post further answer

Answer (score 0):

Like will try to find a string that contains the string 'Gender,Name,Age' as a whole.

Try using

```
where FieldName in('Gender','Name','Age')
```

Comment: This also not helping me. @srworksalot